# iOS app receives GCM notifications only by topics

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

My app implements GCM, but the notifications only receive by topics and not by specific token app.

This it's a example:

```
{
     "registration_ids" : ["dh"],
     "content_available" : true,
     "priority": "high",
     "notification" : {
            "body" : "Winter is coming!",
           "title" : "John Snow"
     }
}
```

The response:

```
{
      "multicast_id":000000,
      "success": 0,
      "failure": 1,
      "canonical_ids": 0,
      "results": [
      {
            "error": "InternalServerError"
      }
      ]
}
```

But the device receives the notifications while they was sent by topics.

```
2015-09-16 22:54:50.931 ExamplePush[1622:379584] Notification received:
{
     "collapse_key" = "do_not_collapse";
     from = "/topics/global";
     message = "{\"id\":102}";
}
```

Please see this:

[Postman 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11aB4tkO8tqclk0SjNzZVZZMkk/view?usp=sharing)

[Postman 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11aB4tkO8tqMVNERFd1MVAwNjg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you using the right registration token? Also does your registration token correctly represent your `APNS token`. For example you need to set this field `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption` based on whether you built your app for Sandbox or prod. Being able to send by topic means that you were able to subscribe the right registration token with that topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parameter "to" into your request in order to get notification and look at the gcm document as well for more information.

```
{
  "to" : " mh7PX-ODCIE:APA91bEdBMCxTJ45SEcCWRyCfzkkZ74YnJl0q0-J8zgIdcZySgR3wu46RXwBHmSzscI6AuI9inYT145C5j30UPMD7soDKRgTGbrcdgZPUahm_Ik-oIUKoUSLLzGNXBeNqnWKDhpHlBfn",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority": "high",
 "notification" : {
        "body" : "Winter is coming!",
       "title" : "John Snow"
 }
}
```

are you checking on postman 
If not then try to check in postman
By this url and append the parameters.

https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
set the header also with your api key of gcm.

[image]

Comment: It isn't the problem. 
The service's response is: Must use either "registration_ids" field or "to", not both . :(

Comment: try just by adding "to" into the dictionary

Comment: Thank you, I add this key to json object, but the server same response

Comment: You can try to delete the app, and reinstall it, the GCM will generate a new registration token for you, and you can use the new one to test.